# What is the process to delete an account?

Tags: support

I asked a couple of days ago to delete my account, using the form https://academia.stackexchange.com/contact provided on the page https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account. I haven't received any answer at the moment, so I'm wondering if there is something else I should do, or if something went wrong in the process, but I'm not really sure to understand why it is not trivial to delete an account (which would not delete the data posted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the network-wide [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/254250):

> Please note that account deletion is not instant. It might take several days for your request to be processed.

I have brought your meta post to the attention of the community team, hopefully you will hear from them soon.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this information does not appear on the account deletion page!

Comment: Well, they weren't kidding on the **several** days ...

Comment: @userxxxxx It is the holiday season so don't be too hasty. I am shocked that you want your 18.9k reputation deleted! Don't leave us!

Comment: They just got in touch with me, apparently, they tried to contact me earlier, but I probably messed things up with changing my contact address. So, sorry, my bad!